# Loopback postgresql connector

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

In my postgres database i have field end_date with datatype as date NOT NULL.

My Database entry is : `2015-09-01`.

When i retrieve data using loopback models its showing as

```
Tue Sep 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST).
```

Whether loopback is converting into someformat? Actually it should be `2015-09-01`.

My mode fetching code:

```
app.models.xxx.find({}, function(err, res) {
        if(err){

        } else {
            for(var i=0; i <res.length; i++){
                console.log("date");
                console.log(res[i].end_date);               
            }
            return callback(null, Amount);
        }
    });
```

Please guide me solve this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am not sure whether the postgres is converting this.

Comment: What is the data type on the column? If you only want date stored Postgres supports a Date Only type (as opposed to timestamp which stores Date Time) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: @scottjustin5000 datatype is DATE.

Comment: Ok. Did you insert the data via loopback models? It seems from the docs that loopback **to** postgres only supports timestamp: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PostgreSQL+connector

Comment: @scottjustin5000  ya i inserted data via loopback models.. whats the solution for this?

Comment: not sure, took a quick peek at the source -->https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/blob/master/lib/postgresql.js . I could be wrong, but it looks like loopback is adding the timestamp. If when you query pg directly the date columns include timestamps, you're only option is to clean up on the way out.